# How to extract specific text and images from docx file and put it in a doc file using python?

Tags: regex, docx

I am trying to extract text and images in between a specified word.I wrote the code for it.Everything is working except images(not showing) and Microsoft equations. I am using docx2txt for this.

```
 from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
import docx2txt
import re

te = docx2txt.process("yo.docx")

y = re.findall(r'Reg.+?(?=Reg|$)', te, flags=re.DOTALL)

x=len(y)


def save_to_file(y,i):
    with open(str(i) + 'Sub.doc', mode="w+", encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
        myfile.write(''.join(y))
        myfile.write('')


for i in range(x):

    save_to_file(y[i],i)
```

Comment: images and equations are not showing because doc2txt only extracts text (see https://github.com/ankushshah89/python-docx2txt). 
You can extract images into a specific folder and then do a file-based search but I think equations are off the table if you want to use python for this.

 C# would be better suited for this kind of microsoft specific task.

Comment: Thank you  so much